# SharePoint Online : Restrict users in People picker by role

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker

In my SharePoint Online environment, in one list, I have three different people picker. Is it possible to configure each of them according to roles?

For e.g.

People picker 1 should only search for users with role Project Manager (sync with AAD so roles are available)
People picker 2 should only search for users with role VP

I saw it is possible to restrict to certain SharePoint group. But is it possible to filter according to role(leverage user profile property maybe) instead of adding all users to separate groups?

Answer (score 0):

OOB its not possible, you can only restrict by Groups.

You can create Audience under User Profile Service based on user profile properties but which will use for Target Audience only